# How about the CONFIDENTIAL docked cells

Tags: front-end, notebooks

I don't know which button I have clicked,but my docked cell is like this now:

[image]

How to reproduce it?What functionality does the CONFIDENTIAL docked cells have?

Comment: Have you not clicked the menu item: Format/Stylesheet/Report/ConfidentialReport?

Comment: @pfactors I'm sure I have not click that...Is there any shortcut to implement it?

Comment: not sure about a shortcut, as I don't use the stylesheets often :)

Comment: @Kuba It will be [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qTsSB.png),do you know what feature in such CONFIDENTIAL environment?Or where can we found any information about it?

Comment: It is the same as the `DockedCells` in the ConfidentialReport stylesheet.  I think you did what @pfactors suggested. There is nothing special about this "environment" beyond what you find in the stylesheet. If you cannot tell us how to reproduce the issue, I think the conclusion is that you (accidentally?) selected the stylesheet.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I did not selected it in there,I even don't know the *Menu bar* have such option. I think a short cut result in this "environment".But I cannot reproduce it..

Comment: What does `CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], StyleDefinitions]` yield?

Comment: This is what it looks like for me with the ConfidentialReport stylesheet in the `"Working"` screen environment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/yd0KV.png

Comment: I had a bug just like this just now. Every time I would save (from menu or with `Ctrl+S)`, instead of saving it would change the style sheet to `ConfidentialReport`. I could not save any notebook. Very strange. I managed to fix it by switching the OS keyboard language, of all things. Now that I have switched the language back the problem is gone and I cannot reproduce it, no matter which language I choose. Very strange, especially considering it happened even if I saved from the menu, which should have nothing at all to do with the keyboard! I am using Mathematica 11.2 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Despite the OP's assertions to the contrary, I think it must be [what @pfactors suggested](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145403/how-about-the-confidential-docked-cells?noredirect=1#comment391031_145403), the ConfidentialReport stylesheet in the `"Working"` screen environment:

[image]

Comment: What features do this environment have?

Comment: @yode Well, it's got a docked cell marked "CONFIDENTIAL," somewhat like the old-school rubber stamp used on paper reports.  It's got automatic numbering of references.  And, of course, it's got lots of style definitions.  Just read through the cell expressions of `SystemOpen@FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd",  "StyleSheets", "Report", "ConfidentialReport.nb"}]`.  -- And it will secretly notify the local security services if you open such a notebook without authorization. ;P