# Delete a Line that doesn't match any cell

Tags: gui-construction, templates

I wrote my notebook using a mathematica style template.

At the beginning I have that line, `Confidential` 
[image]

How can I delete that keeping the template?

Comment: It is a docked cell, you can `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], DockedCells -> {}]` see: [145403](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/145403/5478)

Comment: @Kuba I put that line at the beninning of the notebook and it works, thank you.

Comment: You don't have to keep it.